# Uploading an image from Photo Library or Camera to Firebase storage (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, image, camera, firebase-storage

I want to make a button in my iOS application, when the user clicks on it, he/she gets two options: either choose a photo from the Album or take a photo from the camera to the firebase database.

What's the structure I have to follow to make this possible? Uploading the image to the firebase database!

Comment: How is firebase involved in your question?

Comment: @ EBDOKUM Because I want to save the chosen or taken image to firebase!

Comment: @ EBDOKUM Did you get what I mean?

Comment: I see, yet your question does not ask anything about firebase, why would you include that in your title and tags?¿

Comment: anyway, just google "uiimagepickercontroller"

Comment: @ EBDOKUM Yes, I know that I can make a button to take an image from camera, but my question is, what's the correct structure to upload it to the firbase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have your first *view controller* in storyboard connected to a navigation Controller

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

  var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
   }



     //============================================================================================================================================================

//////
//
//PROFILE PICTURE FUNCTIONS
//
/////




@IBAction func addPictureBtnAction(sender: UIButton) {

    addPictureBtn.enabled = false

    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Select Camera or Photo Library", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .Default, handler: {(cameraAction) in
        print("camera Selected...")

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) == true {

            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
            self.present()

        }else{
            self.presentViewController(self.showAlert("Title", Message: "Camera is not available on this Device or accesibility has been revoked!"), animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    })

    let libraryAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .Default, handler: {(libraryAction) in

        print("Photo library selected....")

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) == true {

            self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            self.present()

        }else{

           self.presentViewController(self.showAlert("Title", Message: "Photo Library is not available on this Device or accesibility has been revoked!"), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

    let cancelAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel , handler: {(cancelActn) in
    print("Cancel action was pressed")
    })

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)

    alertController.addAction(libraryAction)

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



}

func present(){

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
     print("info of the pic reached :\(info) ")
     self.imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}




//Show Alert


func showAlert(Title : String!, Message : String!)  -> UIAlertController {

    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: Title, message: Message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default) { (alert) in
        print("User pressed ok function")

    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    alertController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame

    return alertController
  }

}
```

Firebase Functions :-

```
func profilePictureUploading(infoOnThePicture : [String : AnyObject],completionBlock : (()->Void)) {

    if let referenceUrl = infoOnThePicture[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] {
        print(referenceUrl)

        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([referenceUrl as! NSURL], options: nil)
        print(assets)

        let asset = assets.firstObject
        print(asset)

        asset?.requestContentEditingInputWithOptions(nil, completionHandler: { (ContentEditingInput, infoOfThePicture)  in

            let imageFile = ContentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL
            print("imagefile : \(imageFile)")

            let filePath = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid +  "/\(Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() * 1000))/\(imageFile!.lastPathComponent!)"

            print("filePath : \(filePath)")


                FIRControllerClass.storageRef.child("ProfilePictures").child(filePath).putFile(imageFile!, metadata: nil, completion: {



                    (metadata, error) in

                         if error != nil{

                            print("error in uploading image : \(error)")

                            self.delegate.firShowAlert("Error Uploading Your Profile Pic", Message: "Please check your network!")

                         }
                          else{

                                print("metadata in : \(metadata!)")

                                print(metadata?.downloadURL())

                                print("The pic has been uploaded")

                                print("download url : \(metadata?.downloadURL())")

                                self.uploadSuccess(metadata!, storagePath: filePath)

                                completionBlock()
                    }

            })
        })

    }else{

            print("No reference URL found!")

    }
}






//Saving the path in your core data to search through later when you retrieve your picture from DB


func uploadSuccess(metadata : FIRStorageMetadata , storagePath : String)
{


    print("upload succeded!")

    print(storagePath)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(storagePath, forKey: "storagePath.\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}
```

ps: - This repo link might be useful in future :) https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios (firebase official sample's)

Comment: I tried the first part and it worked! But I'm not going to try the second part until I read a lot about uiimagepickercontroller and see  https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios  examples not just copy and pase the code! Thanks!

Comment: Avoid stemming questions in comment. Post a new one...